# MySql Statement across different rows

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to query a wordpress mySQL database where the values pertaining to each user is spread across different rows (only god knows why they did it that way, why didnt they just put all the user information on one row)

For example

```
 ID  USER_ID FIELD_ID  VALUE
 1      1       2        my name is paul smith
 2      1       3        books
 3      1       4        loggedin
 4      1       5        state=busy
 5      2       2        my name is big boy
 5      2       3        pens
 6      2       4        offline
 7      2       5        state=idle
```

here you can see each row has a different meaning based on the FIELD_ID for the same user

```
 FIELD_ID=2 contains the user name
 FIELD_ID=3 contains mean what they bought
 FIELD_ID=4 means logged in
 FIELD_ID=5 is busy or idle
```

I need to make ONE query that will return all users that are LOGGED IN and STATE=IDLE and bought BOOKS (or bought some other item like pens whatever they want to search for)

so i started off with this php statement

```
   $find="pens";

   $q = "SELECT * FROM table 
          WHERE FIELD_ID='4' AND VALUE='loggedin' 
            AND FIELD_ID='5' AND VALUE='idle' 
            AND USER_ID IN 
               (SELECT USER_ID FROM table WHERE FIELD_ID ='3' AND VALUE LIKE '%$find%')
```

But i dont think this will work because how can 
FIELD_ID = '4' AND VALUE='loggedin' AND FIELD_ID='5' AND VALUE='idle' all at the same time because they are on different rows.

Does anybody know how to make ONE mySQL statement to do it?

Comment: _“(only god knows why they did it that way, why didnt they just put all the user information on one row)”_ - because they did not want a dumb, static system, but one where plugins can easily add additional properties as needed, without having to change database structures all the time. That is something god agrees on with every sensible developer.

Comment: The solution to your problem is to group by the user id, select all records that match _one_ of the conditions (so OR, not AND) via the WHERE clause, and then finaly use HAVING to filter out only those records where the COUNT over the grouped data matches the number of criteria you are checking against.

Comment: use OR instead of AND and just look for FEILD_ID value, the VALUE value is not necessary

Comment: Hello Lelio dont think OR will work because then it would be possible to retrieve information where the user is logged but hes not idle, or idle but hes not logged in it has to be AND

Comment: CBroe, thanks for the comment, could you write the MYSQL statement for what you are talking about, im SQL NOVICE, i got no idea how to make something like what you mentioned, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a self join

```
  SELECT distinct a.user_id 
  FROM table a
  inner join table b on a.user_id = b.user_id and b.field_id = 5 and b.value='idle'
  inner join table c on a.user_id = c.user_id and c.field_id = 4 and c.value = 'loggedin'
  where a.field_id=3 and a.value='BOOK'
```

Comment: scaisEdge, thanks for the comment, but your sql statement doesnt take the login state into acount, it has to return all users that are LOGGED IN and STATE=IDLE and bought BOOKS, three things ANDED together, but seems you are only checking idle and books above, you forgot to check the logged in, could you post another one? thanks

Comment: Thanks very much scaisEdge, i will try it!!

Comment: It worked!!! thanks so much, i would havnt gotten that in a million years!